# How to deduct discrete values in separate columns of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Python (4 weeks in), and have just started working with Pandas and api get requests.  I am pulling api data into a pandas dataframe, and trying to perform basic maths on financial data in separate columns of the DataFrame (i.e., open, high, low, close, volume).

I have written the following code (Note: the parameters and api request url are not verbatim, they are returning proper data sets separated by column):

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

payload = {"key": "value"}

response = requests.get("URL", params=payload)
api_data = json.loads(response.text)
data = pd.DataFrame(api_data)
current_day_delta = data['close'].iloc[-1] - data['open'].iloc[-1]
print(current_day_delta)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

How can I setup the code to calculate current_day_delta, error free?

Comment: The error says that you can not subtract sting from a string. Meaning that `data['close'].iloc[-1]' is string. Please check the data type of both of the columns.

Comment: Hi there,
print(type(data['close']))

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

(same for 'open' column)

Comment: Also, a sample return of print(data['close']):

540    3659.04000000
541    3665.18000000
542    3680.06000000
543    3631.05000000
544    3631.46000000
545    3609.40000000
546    3590.56000000
547    3602.47000000
548    3618.41000000
549    3667.58000000
550    3898.60000000
551    3888.02000000
Name: close, Length: 552, dtype: object

Comment: Can you do following? 1. Print data.head() to see first five columns. 2. If it shows correct columns then print out the values that you are taking for subtraction. That is print data['close'].iloc[-1] and same for other column. Then post the results.Also you are using wrong way to print out data type of pandas columns. The correct way is data['close'].dtype or something similar.

Comment: open column produced 3897.35000000 at position [-1]
close column produced 3898.11000000 at position [-1]

Comment: my results seem to be float, why does it say they're str?

Comment: There may be a string hidden in there somewhere. Or they might appear as floats even though they're strings. You can use the type() function to determine the type of an object (e.g. string, int, float, etc).

Comment: Great, thanks for the help guys really appreciate it.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, thanks very much again.  I managed to retype strings into floats.  Although values are float appearing, they were in fact string type.

Answer (score 1):

If doing `data.head()` prints proper numbers try doing this

```py
# your code
current_day_delta = data['close'].iloc[-1] - data['open'].iloc[-1]

# change this to
current_day_delta = float(data['close'].iloc[-1]) - float(data['open'].iloc[-1])
```

It is likely that the data you fetched from the api returns in a string format which is not identifiable by just printing data.head()